# summarize with bash

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have some data getting by SQL. And I need to summarize with bash without sql.

```
abc=`sudo -u postgres psql admin -t -c "select * from table"`
echo "$abc"
A
B
C
D

dt=`sudo -u postgres psql admin -t -c "slecet * from table"`
echo "$dt"
1
2
3
4
```

Also, there have contained files

```
1/x
1/y
2/y
2/z
3/z
4/x
4/y
4/z
```

and I want to output like this:

```
1 A | x, y
2 B | x, z
3 C | z
4 D | x, y, z
```

I trying some codes but I always failed

```
paste -s -d <(echo "$dt" | while read n; do echo -n " ";done) <(echo "$abc";done ) <(echo find .././ ;done)

A
x
y
z
B
x
y
z
C
x
y
z
D
1
2
3
4
so on..
```

you are free to ask question, if you need more info/details please ask.

Comment: It is probably easier to summarize in the database, but you are specifically asking for a bash solution.  I removed the SQL tag.

Comment: @ÖmerTahaCam : Wouldn't it make more sense to store the data into arrays instead of using string scalars? You are much more flexible when processing arrays.

Comment: @user1934428 yes using array is make more sense. But couldn't convert them to arrays. I tried the IFS to convert the array. And my scenario is like that.

Comment: `readarray` is the appropriate tool to convert to an array, assuming one has bash 4.0 or newer. In older versions of bash, one can use `read -a`. See [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) on why using `array=( $value )` to split on IFS in inappropriate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the precious source and advices. I was trying a lot of things. Actually, I'm assembling the pieces now thanks to you. I learned a lot of things today from here. thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk and expecting the data to be in files (`file1` is the `abc` data, `file2` the `dt`):

```
$ gawk '
ARGIND==1 {                                    # process abc data
    a[FNR]=$0                                  # hash to a
    n++                                        # abc and dt expected to have
    next                                       # same number of records
}
ARGIND==2 {                                    # process dt data
    b[FNR]=$0                                  # hash to b
    next
}
split($0,t,/\//) {                             # process the third set
    c[t[1]]=c[t[1]] (c[t[1]]==""?"":", ") t[2] # hash to c appending
}
END {                                          # in the end
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)                          # n is used
        printf "%s %s | %s\n",b[i],a[i],c[i]   # output
}' file1 file2 file3
```

Output:

```
1 A | x, y
2 B | y, z
3 C | z
4 D | x, y, z
```

If this is a continuous thing you might want to check out the pgsql extension to GNU awk.